# How do I solve QueryResultError in pg-promise

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, pg-promise

Please I am seeing the QueryREsultError when I tested my code in Postman. I am using node.js, express.js, and pg-promise. On testing, the user is created in the Postgres database as expected, but the response instead show **QueryResultError** with the data created and the query in my code as shown below. However, I wanted the response to display just the success message and the token generated. I don't know if the problem is with the **db.none** or the code not generating token. Find my code below:

**CREATEUSER FUNCTION**

```
async createUser(req, res) {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
    const query = `insert into user_table(username, email, email_verified, password, role, created_at, last_login)
                  VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) returning *`;
  const values = [req.body.username, req.body.email, req.body.email_verified, hashedPassword, req.body.role, 'now()', 'now()'];

  try {
    const { rows } = await db.none(query, values);
    const token = Helper.generateToken(rows[0].username);
  return res
    .status(200)
    .cookie('jwt', token, {
      httpOnly: true
    })
    .json({
      success: true
    });
} catch (err) {
    return res.json(err);
  }
},
```

**Helper.generateToken**

```
generateToken(username) {
    const token = jwt.sign({
      username: username
    },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '7d' }
    );
    return token;
  }
}
```

**ERROR SHOWING**

```
{
    "name": "QueryResultError",
    "code": 1,
    "result": {
        "command": "INSERT",
        "rowCount": 1,
        "oid": 0,
        "rows": [
            {
                "id": "8af645cd-5ce5-496a-b07f-db98f4897fee",
                "username": "juljgggg",
                "email": "t@yahoo.com",
                "email_verified": "t@yahoo.com",
                "password": "$2a$12$UmQJ6qKP4nhrWS9kYxySGuBIWv5eyOHzbKtjvLzRQS5qL5bGRssym",
                "role": "Subscriber",
                "created_at": "2020-01-27T13:43:38.122Z",
                "last_login": "2020-01-27T13:43:38.122Z"
            }
        ],
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "id",
                "tableID": 42033,
                "columnID": 1,
                "dataTypeID": 2950,
                "dataTypeSize": 16,
                "dataTypeModifier": -1,
                "format": "text"
            },
            {
                "name": "username",
                "tableID": 42033,
                "columnID": 2,
                "dataTypeID": 25,
                "dataTypeSize": -1,
                "dataTypeModifier": -1,
                "format": "text"
            },
            {
                "name": "email",
                "tableID": 42033,
                "columnID": 3,
                "dataTypeID": 25,
                "dataTypeSize": -1,
                "dataTypeModifier": -1,
                "format": "text"
            },
            {
                "name": "email_verified",
                "tableID": 42033,
                "columnID": 4,
                "dataTypeID": 25,
                "dataTypeSize": -1,
                "dataTypeModifier": -1,
                "format": "text"
            },
            {
                "name": "password",
                "tableID": 42033,
                "columnID": 5,
                "dataTypeID": 25,
                "dataTypeSize": -1,
                "dataTypeModifier": -1,
                "format": "text"
            },
            {
                "name": "role",
                "tableID": 42033,
                "columnID": 6,
                "dataTypeID": 25,
                "dataTypeSize": -1,
                "dataTypeModifier": -1,
                "format": "text"
            },
            {
                "name": "created_at",
                "tableID": 42033,
                "columnID": 7,
                "dataTypeID": 1114,
                "dataTypeSize": 8,
                "dataTypeModifier": -1,
                "format": "text"
            },
            {
                "name": "last_login",
                "tableID": 42033,
                "columnID": 8,
                "dataTypeID": 1114,
                "dataTypeSize": 8,
                "dataTypeModifier": -1,
                "format": "text"
            }
        ],
        "_parsers": [
            null,
            null
        ],
        "_types": {
            "_types": {code ommitted
                }
            },
            "text": {},
            "binary": {}
        },
        "RowCtor": null,
        "rowAsArray": false,
        "duration": 40
    },

}
```

Comment: db.none is for commands that can't return rows.  An INSERT with RETURNING clause is not such a command.  Don't use db.none for it.

Comment: The logic by which methods are named in the protocol is explained right at the beginning - [Methods](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#methods). You are using an incorrect one, should be method `one` in your case, since your query returns one row.

Comment: Thanks @vitaly-t. I changed the db.none to do.one. The error stop displaying but the token is not showing. Postman just returned an empty array like {}. I'll have to look into that. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @jjanes. I have effected the change.